# typescript behaving different in linux getting module not found error

Tags: typescript

I have imported data from another typescript file. while running this code in Windows its working almost fine but same code whenever I am trying to run in Linux environment getting `typeError TS2307: Cannot find module.`

Below are the files which are in same directory.

main.ts

```
import { data } from './importedFile';
```

.
.
.
//other  code

importedFile.ts

```
export const data: any = 'this is dummy data';
```

Error -

```
main.ts:2:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './importedFile'.
```

typescript version - 1.5.3

Comment: Have you run:  npm install?

Comment: Make sure you have typescript installed.

Comment: @HeisAif Typescript is installed with same version on Linux and windows machine but the same code is giving error on Linux but not on windows.